# What is the difference between "enabling", "remedial", and "developmental" courses?

Tags: teaching, terminology

In particular, what differences are there in how these three things are taught?  Is the terminology regional?

Comment: Could you provide some context, please?  In the US, the remedial courses (regardless of what they are called in a particular institution or at a particular point in time) are generally given at community (two-year) colleges.  So it would be helpful to know what level of education you are talking about.  Also, when you say regional, do you mean that it varies by country?

Comment: @aparente001: It would be great if we could change the US educational system to the point where four-year schools no longer had to offer remedial classes, and only community colleges needed to. That is very, very far from being the case today.

Comment: @BenCrowell - My impression was that a much larger proportion of the classes offered at a two-year college are for remediation than at a four-year college.  Maybe I was wrong about that?  Any idea how those proportions compare?  //  (If I needed remedial classes, I would rather take them at a two-year college, to save an arm and a leg in tuition....)

Comment: @aparente001 In what way is the question unclear?  Essentially I am asking about definitions.  There are two good answers, though they do not address the "enabling" aspect of the question.  As Ben Crowell pointed out, remedial instruction is needed at all levels of education.  I do not know what geographic scale might be part of the correct answer to the question.

Comment: "Region" might mean the midwest (within the US); it might mean Canada vs. the US; it might mean English-speaking parts of Asia vs. Northamerica, etc., etc. //  Yes, remedial instruction is needed at many levels -- but it would be really helpful to answer the terminology question to know if you're talking about first grade, graduate school, or something in between.  I hope this helps you clarify what you want to know, so you can get your question re-opened.  It would probably also help to say a little about how this question arose.

Answer (score 5):

My impression is that there's a large element of euphemism and trendiness: "remedial" can sound off-putting or condescending, while "developmental" has fewer bad associations, but they really mean exactly the same thing (namely, a low-level course designed to build skills and fill in missing background in preparation for successfully taking the standard introductory course).

In my experience in the U.S., "remedial" used to be the standard term, but "developmental" has almost completely taken over.  Nowadays, anything described as "remedial" sounds worrisomely old-fashioned.  I haven't run across the term "enabling" in this context, but some quick web searches suggest it is popular in Australia.

There may be differences on average in how remedial or developmental courses are taught, but they reflect how pedagogy changes over time, correlated with but not caused by the change in terminology.  Any previously remedial course could be relabeled developmental without making any further changes.

Answer (score 4):

They mean basically the same thing. I think there's a cyclical nature to this: the situation is fundamentally bad, so once people know what a particular term means (e.g., "remedial"), it becomes something like a slur that people take offense at. So, a new term (e.g., "developmental"), which not everyone knows and hence causes less offense. Likely once people know what this means there will be equivalent offense taken and some other euphemism chosen.

Compare to a similar history of words that mean below average IQ: feeble-minded, dull, idiot, moron, defective, retarded, etc. Obviously the situation is inherently not good, so there's continual churn in the phrases each becoming negatively-connotated, and then some other description is used instead by well-intentioned people.